# JavaScript won't load because of .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I recently wrote a custom CMS script in PHP and now I am trying to have URLS rewritten. So from http://domain.com/page.php?id=ajdsh736hdjd to http://domain.com/information.html.

The PHP site is working fine and I "sort of" got the .htaccess file working. The only thing that does not seem to work is the JavaScript code. When I look at the source of the page I can click on the js file (located in the directory "javascript") and it opens the code in the browser but none of the JS code is executed.

Find below the .htaccess document that I am using (if you have any improvements, please feel free to comment, I am still a noob in url rewrites).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(administrator¦images¦javascript|stylesheet|tools) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ page.php?page=$1
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ member_page.php?page=$1
    RewriteCond $1 !^(search\.php)
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should exempt actual files with a !-f test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These need to be vertical bars:

```
# -------------------------v------v
RewriteRule ^(administrator|images|javascript|stylesheet|tools) - [L]
```

Comment: Where this character `¦` lives in keyboard?

Comment: One should not copy and past blindly from Internet tutorials. Making it a vertical pipe solved the issue.

Comment: @RahilWazir: Depends on your keyboard, on a UK layout it's ALT-GR + `